# Why do some airlines forbid their customers from using travel agents to book their flight tickets?

Tags: bookings, airlines, ryanair, travel-agents

I [read](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/184698/1810):

> Ryanair does not allow you to book via a travel agent, so if you book a Ryanair flight via Kiwi you are in breach of their terms. [Krist van Besien](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6047/krist-van-besien) [7 hours ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184695/what-potential-issues-may-arise-from-using-the-kiwi-online-travel-agency#comment472160_184698)

Why do some airlines forbid their customers from using travel agents to book their flight tickets?

Comment: They have a [full page dedicated to the topic](https://help.ryanair.com/hc/en-gb/categories/12489248662673-Travel-Agent-Bookings)

Comment: @jcaron Thanks! Sorry, I Googled the question but I hadn't added Ryanair as a keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jcaron](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30703/jcaron) [mentioned](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184700/why-do-some-airlines-forbid-their-customers-from-using-travel-agents-to-book-the#comment472172_184700) this interesting [Ryanair webpage](https://help.ryanair.com/hc/en-gb/categories/12489248662673-Travel-Agent-Bookings) that gives some reasons airlines may want to forbid their customers from using travel agents to book their flight tickets: customers may overpay, agents may not communicate the proper passenger information to the airline and agents may violate the airline ToS by checking in on behalf of the passenger.

Quoting their webpage (formatting is mine):

> - [Third-party travel agents] make their profits by adding their own commissions to Ryanair flights and products, which means customers who book through them often pay more than customers who book directly with Ryanair.
> - Some third-party travel agents often do not pass on to us your personal contact and / or payment details, which means we cannot contact you with important updates of your booking or process refunds directly to you.
> - [Some third-party travel agents] may also complete the Ryanair check-in process on behalf of their customers in breach of our General Terms and Conditions of Carriage.

Also, from [flyertalk.com](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/2067758-kiwi-com-update-atlantic-joint-business-partners.html) that [Gray Taylor](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/69620/gray-taylor) [pointed me](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/184707/1810) to, some travel agents encourage behavior that goes against the airline ToS such as hidden city itineraries. E.g., on Kiwi:

[image]

Comment: Note that none of the three bullet points by Ryanair provides an actual justification why Ryanair should prevent you from using a third party agent. Points 1 and 2 are between you and the travel agent, if you don't like how the travel agent behaves that is of no concern to Ryanair. The last point is between Ryanair and the travel agent and has nothing to do with you.