# Haiti to Saint Kitts and Nevis without transiting in the US

Tags: air-travel, transit, haitian-citizens, saint-kitts-and-nevis

Please help me find flights or a direct flight to Saint Kitts and Nevis from Haiti without a layover in the USA.

Comment: Look at the destination lists for the two airports and see which countries appear in both. Canada is an example, though the least practical.

Comment: It’s worth noting that alternative routes may require a visa anyway (or several). While those visas **may** be easier to get than US visas, they may still be a problem.

Comment: Also, you may want to consider travelling to the Dominican Republic by land, that may give you more options and/or be more practical (or not!).

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you don't want to set foot on continental America at all and stay within the islands, it looks like your transit options are these:

- Santo Domingo (connects to Port-au-Prince, Sint Maarten and Saint Kitts)
- Sint Maarten (connects to Port-au-Prince, Santo Domingo and Saint Kitts)

The PaP → Sint Maarten → Saint Kitts or PaP → Santo Domingo → Saint Kitts connections are obviously the most direct, but you'll need to check if tickets are available for these routes at your preferred times, as they seem to be somewhat sporadic. Taking a detour via PaP → Santo Domingo → Sint Maarten → Saint Kitts may actually make for the more convenient connection times.

Discovered via https://panflights.com. You may have to shop around for tickets for these a bit, as the major flight search engines didn't easily offer these in one bundle. Considering you will probably be purchasing individual tickets, making these self-transfers, the safest option may be a longer layover in Santo Domingo.

You can maybe get to Santo Domingo via other means and make this a non-stop Santo Domingo → Saint Kitts flight as well.

You'll be mostly looking at these airlines:

- [AirCentury](https://aircentury.com)

  - Port-au-Prince PAP → Santo Domingo JBQ
  - Santo Domingo JBQ → Sint Maarten SXM
- [Sky High Aviation](https://skyhighdominicana.com)

  - Santo Domingo SDQ → Sint Maarten SXM
  - Santo Domingo SDQ → Saint Kitts SKB
- [Winair](https://www.winair.sx)

  - Sint Maarten SXM → Saint Kitts SKB

Obviously you'll want to take your visa requirements into account for these various countries as well, which I did not research.

Comment: "the safest option may be a longer layover in Santo Domingo" — especially because you'll need to change airports.

Answer (score 10):

Some flight search engines can exclude flights with a layover in countries you want to avoid, e.g. [Kiwi](https://www.kiwi.com):

[image: IMG:]

Example of a flight that it returned:

[image: IMG:]

FYI: [What potential issues may arise from using the Kiwi online travel agency?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/184695/1810)

Similarly, Google Flights gives the option to remove specific airports to avoid for layovers.