# Denied check-in on a code-shared flight of IsrAir and SmartWings: where to complain?

Tags: prague, code-share, denied-boarding, tel-aviv, kiwi

I am traveling with a Kiwi.com-booked trip from CDG->PRG->TLV (and then back). The first segment was run by Czech Airlines and went fine, the second segment was provided by Israir (but operated by SmartWings) and was problematic, flight numbers are 6H7768/QS1286. SmartWings check-in agent told me they could not find me / look me up in the reservation system given my passport information / Israir reservation number and denied check-in. There were 6 other passengers in exactly the same situation. I was forced to pay 211 EUR to buy a replacement ticket from SmartWings.

I am looking for ways to apply for compensation. So far:

- I have kept the initial e-tickets from Israir and my new replacement tickets and receipts.
- Kiwi.com refused to compensate or help in any way.
- SmartWings complaints service refuses to even confirm their check-in personnel has any obligations (like checking in Israir's passengers) towards Israir customers, regardless this flight is somehow a joint flight. They refuse to even confirm it is a code-shared flight, and simply say that they own and fly the aircraft (but it was their check-in agent and they refused to contact Israir, which actually issued my e-ticket) and that the actual operator is Israir. They also refuse to issue a document confirming denial of check-in.
- Israir complaints service does not respond, Israir does not have any offices in TLV airport.

So far it just looks like Israir+SmartWings somehow messed up their reservation computer systems for me and 6 other passengers and simply refuse to compensate or even talk about this.

1. Has anybody visited an actual in-person customer service of Israir in Tel Aviv? Does it exist? Where is it?
2. What would be the relevant higher authorities for further complaints of these airlines misconduct? SmartWings ombudsperson? EU aviation authorities? Israel aviation authorities?
3. How can I find out the actual legal status of this flight? SmartWings claims it is not "code-shared", but on Prague Airport website this flight is displayed to have 4 different flight numbers with 4 different airlines.

I would welcome any advice on fighting back the nasty situation "computer says no"/"contact another airline of code-shared flight" during check-in! There is plenty of information on denied boarding, but not much on denied check-in.

---

**UPD**: does anybody know an Israir English-speaking phone line? I tried both phone numbers at https://www.iaa.gov.il/en/companies/airline-companies/israir-airlines/ and they only playback pre-recorded information, I could not get through to any human to talk to

Comment: This sounds complicated enough to justify hiring one of the law firms that prosecute airline claims for a share of the ultimate award...if any.

Comment: Generally 6H7768 is code share for QS1286, if an agent told you otherwise I think they're wrong (though in principle it may depend on the specific date). So SmartWings does have an obligation towards Israir passengers.

Comment: Here is what SmartWings' complaints agent replied to me: `Dear Vadim, thank you for your email. Flight QS1286 is not code-share flight. This number 6H7768 is Israir flight number, which was operating carrier.  We are not refusing codesharing, but our codeshare flights started by number 8. Kind regards,` and `Dear Vadim, thank you for your email. Unfortunately in this case we are not able to help you because your flight tickets is with Israir. Kindly contact theme directly to provide you with more information. Thank you for your understanding.`. This flight was on 4 Feb, 2024.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184695/what-potential-issues-may-arise-from-using-the-kiwi-online-travel-agency

Comment: I also feared that Kiwi.com did not provide all the necessary information about my passport to Israir (and that this might be the reason for computer issues between Israir and SmartWings), as these passport details are missing from the e-ticket I obtained from Israir. But Kiwi.com continued to claim that my "Israir reservation was confirmed and ticketed" and that they are not a party to this compensation dispute. But overall, yes - this was my last Kiwi.com reservation.

Comment: It may be worth noting that last year IsrAir started the process to buy SmartWings, but there have been no updates for months now. I wonder if things turned sour between them? But ultimately the responsibility is with IsrAir (or maybe Kiwi): they are the ones who sold you the ticket, it is up to them to make sure the ticket is actually valid.

Comment: Israir does not even have an airline office/desk in TLV airport (or any in-person offices at all), despite being Israel's second largest airline. I submitted a complaint with them (no response for now), and I will telephone them as well (yet to find out if they have an English-speaking phone line!)

I suspect that the ticket is somehow valid for Israir computer systems' side, but not for SmartWings computer systems' side, so my (and 6 other passengers') tickets never made it into SmartWings computer. Hard to argue against "computer says no" :(