# Self-transfer through Rome with no luggage. Will I need a visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, london, connecting-flights, easyjet, self-transfer

I am going to book a ticket through the kiwi website, from London to Cairo. The first flight will be with easyJet, from London to Rome. The second flight will be with Wizz Air, from Rome to Cairo. I will not have any check-in bags, thus I would not require leaving the transit area.

I have an Egyptian passport but don't have a visa for Italy. A transit visa is not required, so as long as I stay in the transit area, it will be okay. Will easyJet allow me to board on my first flight, as for them the ticket is only to Rome?

Comment: Note: visa requirement for airside transit depends also on your nationality (or few other special cases). But a single ticket is often a requirements: airlines cannot control you on arrival airports, and they may get huge fine if a passengers has not a valid visa (and they cannot check if you have a valid ticket). In short: do not expect that a low cost airline (or also normal airlines) will risk for you (or do an expensive check).

Comment: You might want to read [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184695/what-potential-issues-may-arise-from-using-the-kiwi-online-travel-agency) before booking with Kiwi. Much simpler to book direct with the relevant airline(s). Altho as the answer says, you can’t do this trip as a self-transfer without a visa

Comment: Did you mean that the second flight will be with Wizz Air from Rome to _Cairo_? Flying back to London would be an odd thing to do if your goal is to end up in Cairo, but it’s not entirely clear to me if you’re actually talking about the return flight there.

Comment: easyJet and Wizz Air are LCCs, low-cost carriers, and thus only offer point-to-point service. They take you from A to B, that's it. If you don't have a visa for B, and would need one to enter that country, they won't board you.

Comment: @dda Please don't use comments to answer the question.

Answer (score 18):

> the question is Will easy jet allow me to board on my first flight as for them the ticket is only to rome.

No, they will not allow you to board the flight to Rome if you don’t have a Schengen visa